# Unabel to reboot emulator from within Android Studio, says

Tags: linux, android-studio, android-emulator, qemu

I am trying to reboot a virtual device, which is currently running. If I choose `Cold Boot Now`

[image]

it swears "AVD .... is already running", which is true.

[image]

How to reboot then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By pressing "X" icon of the emulator tab, you can terminate your emulator.
2. Alternatively, you can "emulate" reboot by long pressing "Power" icon in the emulator menu (1st icon)

[image]